# How to take inputted text from a textarea and display it on another page with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm constructing my website and I wanted to know if it was possible to write something in html's 'textarea' on one page then take that text and print it out using PHP on a new webpage that saves the text last entered.

I just wanted to know how you would go about the process. At the moment I have created a HTML form with three text boxes that I would like to be displayed once the submit button is pressed.

```
<div id="createmeeting">
    <form method="POST">    
    <b>Meeting Title:</b>    
    <textarea name="title" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>    
    <b>Date and Time:</b>    
    <textarea name="date" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>    
    <b>Details:</b>    
    <textarea name="details" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>        
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Save Changes!">
```

Comment: You have to have an action that points to a PHP page.

Comment: Yeah I get that I need to create the PHP to make it work, but I'm interested in dynamically changing the text every time you enter something in the fields then click the button!

Comment: If you want to change the page contents without reloading it, than you should be looking into Javascript and / or jQuery and the use of Ajax to call PHP pages.

Answer (score 0):

First you need an `action` attribute in your `form` tag, that points to the php file that should process the form data:

```
<div id="createmeeting">
    <form method="POST" action="targetfile.php">    
      <b>Meeting Title:</b>    
      <textarea name="title" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>    
      <b>Date and Time:</b>    
      <textarea name="date" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>    
      <b>Details:</b>    
      <textarea name="details" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>        
      <input type="submit" name="go" value="Save Changes!">
    </form>
</div>
```

and in `targetfile.php`

```
<?php
  /* ensure that the data has been posted */
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    /* read the data from $_POST */
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $date= $_POST['date'];
    $details= $_POST['details'];

    /* here you can do whatever you want with the data, output it, store it in a database ... */

    echo "Title: ".$title."<br>";
    echo "Date: ".$date."<br>";
    echo "Details: ".$details;

  }
?>
```